# Docker volumes on first start

Tags: linux, docker, devops

I'm using docker-compose for start dockers. I have image, which have default config inside, but I want to provide my own config based on default by volumes. So I need to get a default, and have able to change it. When I write volumes like this `volumes: - config.json:/etc/config.json` it will create a folder `config.json` on host. How I should do this config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first run, to get the default config from the etc folder. You can mount the entire etc folder. So all the files in the etc folder will be available in your local machine.

```
volumes:
      - ./localetc:/etc
```

Now a new folder called `localetc` will be created in your current directory.

Then `cd localetc && ls -la`. Now you can see your `config.json` file

You can edit your `config.json` with your custom configuration and restart the containers by issuing `docker-compose restart`

Comment: But localetc not will be empty folder? Docker creating empty folders if is it not exists

Comment: Yes, docker will create folders if not exists in your local machine, but when you are mounting a folder (not file). All files present in that container's folder will be available in your newly created `localetc` folder. In the above scenario, all files in your `etc` directory will be available in your `localetc` folder

Comment: Thanks will try it)

Comment: why that volumes creates a folder `setup.sh`?
https://pastebin.com/U9MnqYc0

Comment: `setup.sh` is a file and you should have this file inside your **grafana** directory before starting the containers up. If you don't have a file called `setup.sh` then when you are starting the containers, it will create a folder.

Comment: Looking at your compose file, you should have a folder structure like [this](https://pastebin.com/dZ3iqni0), before starting the container.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this when my config.json file is in the same folder than my docker-compose file.

```yaml
   volumes:
      - ${PWD}/config.json:/etc/config.json
```

I noticed that if I use ./config.json it will create a folder named config.json, so I used ${PWD} instead.

Comment: It will be useful for me, thanks. But How can I get a default config from container?

Comment: If its from the container, you create the volume from the folder - /etc/folder:/etc/folder/ (in the container) and not the file, so you can have it on your host.

Comment: created folder.
And got error:
`ERROR: for grafana  Cannot start service grafana: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/setup.sh\": permission denied": unknown`

`ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`